# Convert a PDF form to a "locked" flat PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I'm using iTextSharp to fill a PDF form, and I want the PDF to be transformed into a flat PDF.

I tried using PdfStamper.FormFlattening, but it only "locks" the form, which can be unlocked easily.

I want the resulting PDF to be as the file generated when you "Print as PDF" the PDF form. Smaller with all static text (no more form).

Thanks

Comment: *I tried using PdfStamper.FormFlattening, but it only "locks" the form* - then you did something wrong or have a peculiar form. Please share the relevant code and PDF for analysis.

Comment: Without code we can't help you